# start: Job already running: Unity7

Tags: terminal

I am setting up the Claymore DualMiner Software and, after executing `start` in the folder's directory (in the terminal)to begin the mining, I receive this message:

```
start: Job is already running: unity7
```

I don't understand how this could be possible. All help is greatly appreciated.
[image]